# Seventy Topics - 6*6 = 36 paramitas

Tags: paramitas

In our local group we are working with Dön Dün Chu, the 70 points (from Abhisamayalankara) by Jetsün Chökyi Gyaltsan .
In I.7 (putting on the armor) the 6 paramitas are mentioned. It is said that they interlock in a cross product, meaning there are actually 36 resulting traits to consider in your practise.

1. generosity, giving of oneself (sbyin-pa)
2. virtue, morality, discipline, proper conduct (tshul-khrims)
3. patience, tolerance, forbearance, acceptance, endurance (bzod-pa)
4. energy, diligence, vigor, effort (brtson-’grus)
5. one-pointed concentration, contemplation (bsam-gtan)
6. wisdom, insight (shes-rab)

Now, I have my problems understanding two things: where is the difference between n*m and m*n? And what is n*n (reflexive)? I could not find any sources on that and my teacher had no time to answer this in detail.

The reflexive relations only make sense to me as in "generosity *in general*" for example but I heard there is more to it. Maybe I need starting help as in how to connect each point with the others.

Answer (score 0):

**where is the difference between `n*m` and `m*n`?**

I don't know about this Buddhist doctrine, but relations like these are distinguished/distinct in the [I ching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Ching#Hexagrams) for example -- e.g. [heaven over mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hexagrams_of_the_I_Ching#Hexagram_33) versus [mountain over heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hexagrams_of_the_I_Ching#Hexagram_26).

The hexagrams include the reflexive too, e.g. [heaven over heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hexagrams_of_the_I_Ching#Hexagram_1) and [mountain over mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hexagrams_of_the_I_Ching#Hexagram_52).

Perhaps (this is just my guess) the difference is that one is the basis for the other -- e.g. "because of virtue, you are generous" versus "because of generosity, you are virtuous" (or if not "because of" then "based on" or "conditioned by", or something like that).

Answer (score -1):

At first glance, this looks like an algebraic expression for practicing the paramitas. If n * m and m * n were distinct, then there would be 72 resulting traits. If there are only 36, that implies that these equations are the same and interchangeable.

As for n * n, I can't say for certain, but if you look at it like a formula, n * n = n^2. If you "square" your own application of a quality, you are doubling its power and reinforcing it's imprint onto your own habits and routines. If you think you've gone deep enough, then you have to go deeper.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, what the OP meant by "the difference between n\*m and m\*n". How many ways are there of combining 6 things, how many possible pairs are there? The answer is 36: i.e. "any of 6" multiplied by "any of 6". However that answer (36 pairs) assumes that sequence is significant, e.g. that "A+B" and "B+A" are two different pairs, and it assumes that a self-pair like "A+A" or "B+B" is a valid pair -- and that's what the question is asking, i.e. "my teacher said 36" however "how is A+B different from B+A?" and "what's the meaning of a reflexive pair (a self-pair)"?